# changing multiple column names with a single query

Tags: sql, ms-access

in ms-access, how to write a query / DDL to change multiple column names with a single query.

Comment: Are you certain you need to do this? Why not create a saved query that aliases the columns? If you want a permanent change, I see no reason to code it and not just do it by hand in the Access table designer. It will take longer to code it than it would to just do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new table, copy data, drop old table

[ALTER TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) does not support multiple ...ALTER COLUMN clauses

You could ADD multiple columns on one go, populate then, then drop the old columns.
Multiple ADDs are supported.

Comment: And, of course, concern yourself with any relatonships or indexes based on those columns.